# phase-stability two op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, stability

I'm trying to simulate two op-amps back-to-back (G=30 each) in LTSpice and work out if they will be stable.  If I look at the .ac analysis after the fist op-amp I have good phase margin (about 60 degrees). If I look at the phase-margin after the second op-amp my phase  is now -200 degrees - i.e. unstable

Do I have to consider the total phase from both opamps (which I think is what LTSpice is doing) or is only the phase around each op-amp important.  i.e to first order I can consider each op-amp independent? Is the number I should be looking at is -123 in the ratio and hence I should be fine.

Circuit and plots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: "...or is only the phase around each op-amp important. i.e to first order I can consider each op-amp independent? " Yes, they can be consideredas independent.

Comment: It's probably more important to show the loop response rather than the closed-loop response if you want to talk about phase margin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to consider the phase around the feedback loop.  Since you don't have feedback from the output of the second to the input of the first you can treat the two independently.

If you wanted to feedback from the output back to the input you would have problems.

You have rather low feedback resistors - is there a reason for that?  They will consume a large amount of power and of your output current capability just to drive the feedback.

It will help reduce Johnson noise but is not really necessary in the second stage as noise there will be dwarfed by that in the first stage.

Comment: Thanks - The first set of resistors are for Johnson noise consideration - The second should be a lot larger then the schematic above shows (200 and 6k)